# How do Hex Warrior, Pact of the Blade and Improved Pact Weapon Interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, eldritch-invocations

Ok so per this [Are the hex warrior weapon and the pact of the blade weapon the same or different](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111371/are-the-hex-warrior-weapon-pact-of-blade-weapon-the-same-or-different) I know they are different. I just picked up improved pact blade and I need to know how they all fit together.

I'm trying to get a hand crossbow for my off hand and a long sword for my main hand. So I ritualize my hand crossbow and summon a longsword when battle starts.

My character is level 5 has an 18 Charisma and Crossbow Expert feat. My understanding is that attacking with the Long Sword will be +8(+3 PFB, +4 Cha, +1 Imp) to hit and +5(+4 Cha, +1 Imp) damage while the hand crossbow will be at +7(+3 PFB, +4 Cha) to hit and +4(+4 Cha) damage. Is this correct or do they both get the same bonuses?

Comment: How will you load your Hand Crossbow? You still need a free hand.

Comment: Crossbow expert says i ignore the reloading porperty but if it helps you can but dagger for off hand

Comment: Removing _loading_  just lets you use it more than once per round

Comment: Then put that in your answer and switch the crossbow to a dagger

Comment: However, this question is about the interaction of those warlock features, not Crossbow Expert. You might be interested in these Q&As about Crossbow Expert: [Do you still need a free hand to reload if you take crossbow expert?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/72233/do-you-still-need-a-free-hand-to-reload-if-you-take-crossbow-expert) And: [Wielding a Hand Crossbow and a Rapier with Crossbow Expert Feat while dropping & picking up the Rapier](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122602/wielding-a-hand-crossbow-and-a-rapier-with-crossbow-expert-feat-while-dropping)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Your calculations are all correct.

Here are your relevant statistics:

- Your **Charisma** is 18 (**+4**).
- Your **proficiency bonus** is **+3** (5th level).
- You can use Crossbow Expert to attack with the hand crossbow after attacking with the longsword, presuming you have a free hand at some point to reload it. Alternatively, you could substitute a dagger without changing the calculations, so this feat isn't relevant to the question.

Here's the scenario for your **longsword**:

- You are armed with a longsword that is your Pact of the Blade weapon.
- You are proficient with it both because it is your pact weapon and because you have proficiency with martial weapons as a Hex Warrior.
- You can apply your Hex Warrior benefit to it because it is a pact weapon of any type, so you can use CHA for the attack and damage.
- You can apply your Improved Pact Weapon benefit to it because it is a pact weapon, so it gains +1 to attack and damage.
- Your **to-hit bonus** will be your proficiency bonus + your CHA modifier + your Improved Pact Weapon bonus = +3 +4 +1 = **+8**.
- Your **damage bonus** is the same as the above without adding the proficiency bonus = **+5**. The damage type is **magical** because it is a pact weapon.

Here's the scenario for your **hand crossbow**:

- You are armed with a non-magical hand crossbow.
- You are proficient with it because you have proficiency with martial weapons as a Hex Warrior.
- You can apply your Hex Warrior benefit to it because you channeled your will through it, so you can use CHA for the attack and damage.
- You *can't* apply your Improved Pact Weapon benefit to it because it isn't a pact weapon.
- Your **to-hit bonus** will be your proficiency bonus + your CHA modifier = +3 +4 = **+7**.
- Your **damage bonus** is the same as the above without adding the proficiency bonus = **+4**. The damage type is **non-magical** because none of your benefits cause it to be magical.

So all of **your calculations were correct** as presented in your question.